# Using ODEINT on codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to install ODEINT on codeblocks to try to write a program that solves ODEs. I've never used external libraries before so I have no idea on how to get started. 
After spending a while searching online and watching videos on youtube, here's what I've tried to do:

I downloaded the Odeint zip file from http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/index.html. After uncomprssing it I found a bunch of header files in its sub folders ( but no .libus files).

1. I've read that one way to being using it is to create a project and then add all the header files found in the odeint file. However you also need to to use the linker to link a .libus file, which I could not find. I found this confusing and didn't get too far with it.

2.The other thing I tried to do was use a empty file and save it as .cpp in a new folder (I usually work with such files, not projects). Then I dug through the odeint file to find odeint.hpp, which I copied and saved in the same folder as my .cpp file, then I included #include "odeint.hpp" and saved the remaining 
 odeint files ( ie. the directory  ) in the same folder, so that during compilation c++ could find them using odeint.hpp.
This didn't work either.

I've a tried bunch of other things as well that I found online. I didn't really understand them and followed the instructions but nothing worked. I get this exact error : fatal error: boost/numeric/odeint.hpp: No such file or directory in all cases

If someone could help me with installing and using ODEINT, I'd really really appreciate it

Comment: From the link you posted: _"ODEINT is a header only library"_. So there is no library to link.  Just #include the header files in you source files.

Comment: @RichardCritten I tired to do that in my second step, but it didn't work

Comment: _"Didn't work_" is unclear, you need to say exactly what went wrong.

Comment: It gives me this exact error : fatal error: boost/numeric/odeint.hpp: No such file or directory|

Comment: Even though I have the boost/ file on the same folder as my .cpp file

Comment: This is when I use  #include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

Comment: @user129048 You failed to do what would be the obvious and the proper way to use a library that consists of headers -- set your `include` paths correctly in your project.   There is no need to place the headers anywhere near your source code -- it can live in its own space on your system.  Now how you do set the include path with CodeBlocks is another issue, but any C++ compiler / project has the ability for you to set the include path and where the compiler will search for the include files.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I managed to get it working after messing around with the compiler setting like you suggested